# Trying to get property of non-object laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

Всем привет, помогите с проблемой, я так полагаю что проблема в самой ссылке и как её правильно описать не понимаю.

> Если я удаляю ссылки в представлении с категориями, то переходя
>   напрямую не по ссылкам, всё работает и сортирует все статьи по
>   категориям.

Это контроллер `class ArticlesController extends Controller`

```
public function index ()
{
    $articles = Article::all();
    $category = Category::all();

    return view('index')->with(compact('articles', 'category'));
}

public function show($id)
{
    $articles = Article::where('id', $id)->first();
    $category = Category::all();

    return view('articles')->with(compact('articles', 'category'));
}

public function showAll ($category_id)

{
    $category = Category::where('name', $category_id)->firstOrFail();
    return view('categories')->with(compact('category'));
}
```

Это представление из которого хочется перейти в категории, я так полагаю именно тут и ошибка:

```
  @foreach($category as $cat)
                        <li><a class="nav-link text-white" href="{{ route('articlesShow', ['id'=>$cat->name]) }}">{{ $cat->name }}</a></li>
        @endforeach
```

Роут:

```
Route::get('/categories/{category_id}', 'ArticlesController@showAll')->name('articlesShow');
```

Модель Category:

```
 protected $table = 'categories';
protected $fillable = ['name'];

public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class, 'category_id');
}
```

> Вроде проходит по ссылке без ошибок, но теперь другая ошибка:

`Property [articles] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /home/vagrant/Code/nexta/resources/views/categories.blade.php)`

Вот представление:`categories.blade.php`

```
 @foreach($categories->articles as $article)
                    <div class="col-6 col-lg-4"> <!--Post -->
                        <img src="{{ asset('upload/image/1.jpg') }}" width="255"  alt="..." class="rounded img_size">
                        <h4> {{ $article->title }}</h4>
                        <h6>Категория: <a href="/"> {{ $article->category->name }}</a></h6>
                        <h6>Автор: {{ $article->author }}</h6>
                        <p>{{ $article->text }} </p>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{{ route('articleShow', ['id' =>$article->id]) }}"> Читать &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div><!--EndPost-->
                @endforeach
```

Comment: Так в какой строке именно ошибка? в `laravel.log` как минимум должно было вывести

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Там много ошибок: Next ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/vagrant/Code/nexta/resources/views/layouts/site.blade.php) (View: /home/vagrant/Code/nexta/resources/views/layouts/site.blade.php) in /home/vagrant/Code/nexta/storage/framework/views/ec3803a352b605b1ee4154d88d044f1d78809c53.php:46

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рискну предположить что ваш цикл находится в представлении `categories`, и получается что у вас с контроллера в переменной `$category` приходит не массив категорий, а одна категория, в этом и ошибка в самом цикле, переделайте выборку в методе `showAll` на выбор всех категорий:

```
$categories = Category::where('name', $category_id)->get(); //обратите внимание что название переменной изменил под множественное число
```

Так же в самом цикле вы в значение `id` передаете `name` что тоже будет не правильно, верный вариант:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <li><a class="nav-link text-white" href="{{ route('articlesShow', ['id'=>$category->id]) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Если же вызывается представление из другого метода, тогда вариант только один - нет поля `name` в модели `Category`, или же проблема даже не в этом куске кода.

Comment: Вроде проходит по ссылке без ошибок, но теперь другая ошибка: Я правку сделал вопроса.